# How show text style as bold when in Android EditText was disabled in layout xml?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my edit text, I have mentioned text style as bold and the edit text was noneditable. I need to show the text field as in bold but it was not working.

**Here is my EditText Sample:**

```
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_padding_5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance">   
                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/amount"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:maxLength="7"
                            android:text="999.99"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:focused="false"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:textSize="18"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead making it `android:enabled="false"`
try as below

```
android:focusable="false"
android:longClickable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this :

> android:enabled="false"

edittext was non editable

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/amount"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:maxLength="7"
            android:text="999.99"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
```